# NavigatorIOS - Is there a viewDidAppear or viewWillAppear equivalent?

Tags: react-native

I'm working on porting an app to React-Native to test it out. When I pop back to a previous view in the navigator stack (hit the back button) I'd like to run some code.  Is there a viewWillAppear method?  I see on the Navigator there is a "onDidFocus()" callback which sounds like it might be the right thing.. but there doesn't appear to be anything like that on NavigatorIOS

Comment: NavigatorIOS has all the same methods as Navigator I think.

Comment: Well viewDidAppear for example isn't a method on the navigator in iOS, is a method on the viewController when it appears. Plus I think only methods Facebook choose to expose to JavaScript are available, not nessasarily all of them.  But maybe there's one exposed that will help, I'm just unaware

Comment: I was referring to you saying "on the Navigator there is a "onDidFocus()".. but there doesn't appear to be anything like that on NavigatorIOS"

Comment: Ah right. I see what you're saying.

Answer (score 14):

I find a way to simulate viewDidAppear and viewDidDisappear in UIKit,
but i'm not sure if it's a "right" way.

```
componentDidMount: function() {
    // your code here

    var currentRoute = this.props.navigator.navigationContext.currentRoute;
    this.props.navigator.navigationContext.addListener('didfocus', (event) => {
        //didfocus emit in componentDidMount
        if (currentRoute === event.data.route) {
            console.log("me didAppear");
        } else {
            console.log("me didDisappear, other didAppear");
        }
        console.log(event.data.route);
     });
},
```

Answer (score 6):

For people who are using hooks and react navigation version 5.x, I think you can do this to expect similar behavior of viewDidAppear:

```
  import React, {useCallback } from "react";
  import { useFocusEffect } from "@react-navigation/native";

  const SomeComponent = () => {
      useFocusEffect(
        useCallback(() => {
          //View did appear
        }, [])
      );
      //Other codes
  }
```

For more information, refer https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-focus-effect/

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution to simulate viewDidAppear with latest React Navigation version:

```
componentDidMount() {
     var currentRoute = this.props.navigation.state.routeName;
     this.props.navigation.addListener('didFocus', (event) => {

         if (currentRoute === event.state.routeName) {
             // VIEW DID APPEAR
         }
     });
}
```

Thanks Jichao Wu for the idea :)

Comment: so far looks like a sweet way of doing it.

Comment: `this.props.navigation.state.routeName` throws an error as `this.props.navigation.state` is undefined. there is `getState()` function on `navigation` but that also doesn't have a `routeName` property, it has `routes` and `routeNames` which are arrays, so we don't know how to access the current `routeName` from there

Answer (score 0):

If you are using React Navigation, use this:

```
    componentDidMount(){
        this.props.navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
            // put your code here
        });
    }
```

Basically you are adding a `focus` event when component is first mounted. It will be called whenever (including the first time too) the component is focused. Ideally you'd also need to remove listener on unmount by capturing the value returned from `addListener` call and call that returned value (which is actually the unsubscribe function).

Answer (score -2):

I've created a custom button with `onLeftButtonPress` to handled the back to run code as per https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/26

> The way to get around it is to either set your custom back button on the left side, or to implement - viewWillDisappear: in iOS.

Comment: you can also go back with back swipe

Answer (score -4):

You can use ComponentWillMount or if you're leaving the view you can use ComponentWillUnmount which will run some code on exit.