# How to tell when a view will appear with ReactNavigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm using ReactNavigation and am wondering how I can tell when a view will appear (so that I can trigger a data refresh).  I see this example using a different navigator [NavigatorIOS - Is there a viewDidAppear or viewWillAppear equivalent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29619673/navigatorios-is-there-a-viewdidappear-or-viewwillappear-equivalent) but not sure how it would work with https://reactnavigation.org/.

I see the console.log on the navigation dispatches - but is there some event handler that I can hook into on the screen/component level to know if that component/screen is in the foreground?  Should I hook into the `getStateForAction` method somehow?  https://reactnavigation.org/docs/routers/api .  I don't want to really create custom route handlers per se, just to detect if the view is entering foreground/will appear, and I'm guessing I can use the navigation event to do that somehow.

Comment: Do you mean for example when you pop a view from stack? If the component is loaded for first time componentWillMount() is called

Comment: I mean every time that particular screen/component is active in the view, e.g. when the user navigates to the home screen, or when an application event navigates to that screen.

Comment: Have you figures out a way to do this? I'm struggling with the same. Especially with tab bars all the views are usually loaded immediately but I'm just interested in an event when the user actually loads a screen.

Comment: Yes - I'll update the question with an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I got this working by creating a redux action and store that tracks the active screen and attaching it to the root navigation `onNavigtionChange` event.

```
      <RootNavigation
        ref={nav => { this.navigator = nav; }}
        onNavigationStateChange={(prevState, currentState) => {
          const currentScreen = this.getCurrentRouteName(currentState);
          const prevScreen = this.getCurrentRouteName(prevState);
          if (prevScreen !== currentScreen) {
            this.props.broadcastActiveScreen(currentScreen);
            {/*console.log('onNavigationStateChange', currentScreen);*/}
          }
        }}
      />
```

actions

```
import { createAction } from 'redux-actions';
import type { Dispatch } from '../state/store';

export const SCREEN_WILL_APPEAR = 'SCREEN_WILL_APPEAR';
const createScreenWillAppearAction = createAction(SCREEN_WILL_APPEAR);
export const broadcastActiveScreen = (activeScreen: string) => (
  (dispatch: Dispatch) => {
    dispatch(createScreenWillAppearAction(activeScreen));
  }
);
```

Reducer

```
export default handleActions({
  [SCREEN_WILL_APPEAR]: (state, action) => {
    return Object.assign({}, state, {
      activeScreen: action.payload,
    });
  },
}, initialState);
```

In the screen component

```
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.activeScreen === 'MyScreenName' && nextProps.activeScreen !== this.props.activeScreen) {
     // put your on view will appear code here
    }
   }
```

Answer (score 3):

I think the `didFocus`, `willFocus`, `didBlur` and `willBlur` events will fit your needs.

You need to set/unset them in the `componentWillMount` and `componentWillUnmount` methods.

See the docs [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-prop.html#addlistener-subscribe-to-updates-to-navigation-lifecycle) or [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-events.html). The examples are not the best though. Feel free to ask if you want an example!

Answer (score 1):

When using *React Navigation*, your provide components as screens. You can handle what you want inside them. These are the react components, So they have *componentWillMount* and *componentDidMount*. It's better to use *componentDidMount* because it's not blocking rendering.

For the first time component rendered, *componentDidMount* is a good option. For the next times, you should use *componentWillReceiveProps*. This function called when component rendered again.

**update:**
If the props not changed, *componentWillReceiveProps* will not triggered. And i think it happened in your situation. You should write a custom router or use a timer to trigger in intervals.

Comment: But componentDidMount only fires once and even if its not focused.  i.e. it fires once on app start - not when the screen appears - and the screen can appear or focus multiple times.

Comment: I think I had an issue in that the componentWillReceiveProps will trigger many times even if the screen doesn't change so it becomes a difficult event to tie to a view will appear scenario